# Implement of listener does not work

Tags: java, actionlistener, onmouseclick

```
public class ShapeDisplayer implements ActionListener {
    private static final int Width = 50; 
    private static final int Frame_Width = 400;
    private static final int Frame_Height = 600; 
    static JPanel DrawPanel;
    static JButton carButton;
    static JButton eclipseButton;
    static JButton compButton;

    public static void main (String args[])
    {
        // create frame
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Drawing Applet"); 

        // create panels
        JPanel ButtonPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
        DrawPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

        // create Icons
        CarIcon Acar = new CarIcon(Width);
        EclipseIcon doubleCircle = new EclipseIcon(20);
        CompositeIcon compIcon = new CompositeIcon(50, 60);

        // create buttons
        carButton = new JButton(Acar);
        eclipseButton = new JButton(doubleCircle);
        compButton = new JButton(compIcon);

        // panel config
        ButtonPanel.setBounds(0,0,Frame_Width,100);
        DrawPanel.setBounds(0,100,Frame_Width,Frame_Height-100);

        // add panels'components
        ButtonPanel.add(eclipseButton);
        ButtonPanel.add(carButton);
        ButtonPanel.add(compButton);

        // add frames' components
        frame.add(ButtonPanel);
        frame.add(DrawPanel);

        // frame config
        frame.setSize(Frame_Width, Frame_Height);
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        if (e.getSource() == carButton)
        {
            DrawPanel.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) { 
                  CarIcon car = new CarIcon(Width, e.getX(), e.getY());
                  JLabel lable = new JLabel (car);
                  DrawPanel.add(lable);
              } 
            });     
        }

    }
}
```

Im trying to implements this program to draw on the panel on mouseclick, for example if the button is carButton, then whenever i click on the panel, a car icon will be drew. I implemented the listener, but when I clicks on the panel nothing appears on the panel.I'm adding the listener on the Jframe, do I need to add it on the Jpanel for the program to work properly? Can someone help to fix this program, thank in advance.

[image]

Comment: You never add the listener to anything

Comment: actually I don't know how to do this, Do I need to use anonymous class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actionPerformed method does not get invoked when a button is clicked. Because it is not bound to any of the buttons.

For instance, the carButton can be added an action listener as follows.

```
carButton = new JButton(Acar);
carButton.addActionListener(new ShapeDisplayer());
```

Note that as this code is in the main method, "this" cannot be used to add an action listener. A new object of ShapeDisplayer class needs to be instantiated.

Also the DrawPanel may need a repaint for the changes to take effect. Invoking revalidate method does that.

```
 DrawPanel.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) { 
        CarIcon car = new CarIcon(Width, e.getX(), e.getY());
        JLabel lable = new JLabel (car);
        DrawPanel.add(lable);
        DrawPanel.revalidate();
    } 
});
```

Comment: I tried to add this line you mention above `carButton.addActionListener(new ShapeDisplayer());` but i got this error message `The method addActionListener(ActionListener) in the type AbstractButton is not applicable for the arguments (new ShapeDisplayer(){})`

Comment: The error you reported occurs if attempted to add an instance which does not implement the ActionListener interface as an actionListener. Was there any change to interfaces implemented by ShapeDisplayer class ?